# When I swipe back got no video in Fragment only sound and TextView in ViewPager2

Tags: android, libvlc

I'm using ViewPager2 for playing in MediaPlayer (libVLC) videostream from cameras. When I swiped forward everything works good. But wheh I  swiped back got no video in Fragment  only sound and TextView.

Here is code of Fragment

```
`public class PageFragment extends Fragment{
@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer[3];
        pageNumber = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
        libVlc = new LibVLC(getActivity());

        mediaPlayer[pageNumber] = new MediaPlayer(libVlc);
        urls = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.urls);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if  (!mediaPlayer[pageNumber].isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer[pageNumber].play();
            int st=mediaPlayer[pageNumber].getPlayerState();
            Log.i("Play"+pageNumber, String.valueOf(st));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if  (mediaPlayer[pageNumber]!=null && mediaPlayer[pageNumber].isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer[pageNumber].pause();
            int st=mediaPlayer[pageNumber].getPlayerState();
            Log.i("Pause"+pageNumber, String.valueOf(st));
        }
    }

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
     
        TextView pageHeader = result.findViewById(R.id.displayText);
        String header = "Camera " + (pageNumber+1);
        pageHeader.setText(header);

        
            videoLayout = result.findViewById(R.id.videoLayout);
            mediaPlayer[pageNumber].attachViews(videoLayout, null, false, false);

            Media media = new Media(libVlc, Uri.parse(urls[pageNumber]));
            media.setHWDecoderEnabled(true, false);
            media.addOption(":network-caching=600");

            mediaPlayer[pageNumber].setMedia(media);
            media.release();
            mediaPlayer[pageNumber].play();
        

        return result;
    }
.....
}
```

And here layout for Fragment

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/displayText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="500dp"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

<org.videolan.libvlc.util.VLCVideoLayout
    android:id="@+id/videoLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/displayText"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>
```

Same happens when MainActivity goes in Pause and than come back to the foreground.

Know some body how to resolve this trouble ?
Thank You.

P.S.
After backswaping I got this in log:

```
E/VLC: [945e9a00/65e2] libvlc decoder: buffer deadlock prevented
E/VLC: [94b4db00/65f9] libvlc vout display: can't get Video Surface
E/VLC: [94812a80/65f9] libvlc video output: video output display creation failed
E/VLC: [936b4000/65fa] libvlc vout display: can't get Video Surface
E/VLC: [94812a80/65fa] libvlc video output: video output display creation failed
E/VLC: [945e9a00/65f2] libvlc decoder: avcodec_send_packet critical error
E/VLC: [94b4e900/65fb] libvlc vout display: can't get Video Surface
E/VLC: [94812a80/65fb] libvlc video output: video output display creation failed
```

Answer (score 0):

LibVLC gets discarded in these cases, you need to renew the libvlc objects.

Comment: Hi! 
What You  mean, recreate  libvlc objects or redraw ?

Comment: yes thats what I mean